# How to make dynamic css color filling boxes in html?

Tags: angular

In below image, I have `mat_icon` like 3 small boxes. Here I need to fill the color based on status_name.

For Example:

1. `status_name` is Not started , need to fill red color in one box
2. `status_name` is production started, need to fill two small boxes with yellow color
3. `status_name` is production completed, need to fill 3 boxes with green color.. How can we do this in dynamically.

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="process">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <div>{{element.mlc_status?.status_name}}</div>
               <div> <mat-icon>crop_7_5</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon>crop_7_5</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon>crop_7_5</mat-icon></div>
             </td>
          </ng-container>

[![Mentioned Image][1]][1]


**Update:**

Here's the [stackblitz][2] requested in comments.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb4t4.png
  [2]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewuxsm
```

Comment: Please provide minimal working example in https://stackblitz.com/ with your code, which would helpful to better understand your issue..

Comment: @Maniraj ,,here I have given stackblitz,, But not able to show 3 icons..

Comment: let me explain, <mat-icon>crop_7_5</mat-icon> => this code will contain small box. Like this i have 3 box for each record. need to fill color based on status name..

Comment: Really not an useful link.. Your issue is not there and also it is another material design stackblitz.. Please provide your code if you really need solution..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewuxsm

Comment: @ManirajMurugan here I have given stackblitz of my code

Comment: You mean like this?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyc1g4

Comment: @ManirajMurugan  exactly.. Thank you so much.. You saved my time..

Comment: In future try to do like this when you post a question, Explain what you have done and provide such example links that will make us to provide solution in easier way otherwise you won't get your solution needed..

Comment: I have posted as an answer, feel free to accept the solution if it solves your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the stackblitz given in the comments section of question, it is clear that OP is trying to achieve the result of making the colors in each box at separate level,

So to do so you could use [**[ngStyle]**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to conditionally render the `background-color` based on the status to the boxes..

First box condition:

(Accepts all three status **Not started, Production started and Completed** (Red, Yellow, and Green))

```
<div class="box" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':    
   element.status_name == 'Not started' ? 'red' : 
   element.status_name == 'Production started' ? 'yellow' :
   element.status_name == 'Completed' ? 'green' : null
 }"></div>
```

Second box condition:

(Accepts **Production started and Completed** (Yellow and Green color))

```
 <div class="box" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 
  element.status_name == 'Production started' ? 'yellow' :
  element.status_name == 'Completed' ? 'green' : null
 }"></div>
```

Third box condition:

(Accepts **Completed** (Green color only))

```
 <div class="box" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 
 element.status_name == 'Completed' ? 'green' : null
 }"></div>
```

> [**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyc1g4)

Comment: Thank you for this solution.. I need one more feature in this.. For Production started status need to fill the 3rd box based on percentage value.. could you update this??

Comment: @Rekha, What do you mean by percentage value here?? I do't find any percentage here.. Can you elaborate in detail or else raise a new question with necessary details..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewuxsm @maniraj.. can you refer this??

Comment: @Rekha, I can refer that but where is the right explanation from you?? Unless you give your detail explanation regarding your expected output, it is tough to answer..

Comment: ,Right now, we have solution if status is production started, it should fill yellow color only 2 boxes,, but now expected output => we have 2 fields to calculate percentage value, based on that value need to fill the 3 rd box also.. For example if calculated percentage value is 50% => 3rd box should fill half space or 75% => 3rd box should fill 3/4 th space,, like this.. hope ,Now  you can understand expected output..

Comment: @Rekha, Include that percentage calculation also , I cannot assume in which way you will calculate the percentage.. Just give the newData array with percentage details and I will look into it..

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz..   stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewuxsm

Comment: @Rekha, Here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glqewm